# Some part of my Website's CSS is not being implemented when uploaded on Github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I recently made a simon game using JS,HTML5,CSS3 and Bootstrap v4.5.Now the issue occurs on phones i.e. when display of viewport is below 726px.While testing locally on Chrome developer tools the site looks the **way I want the website to look**.Below is the image on Chrome developer tools
https://www.flickr.com/photos/189671520@N03/50243919798/in/dateposted/ 
Below is the screenshot of the same page taken on actual pone https://www.flickr.com/photos/189671520@N03/50244763957/in/dateposted/

The key difference is on the edge of each color ,the border radius as well as the border color black is not being applied !. Looking forward for help.
the code for CSS is

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
  background-color: #011f3f;
  color: #fef2bf;
}
.btn {
  margin: 3px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 210px;
  width: 210px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.btn-close:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: right;
}
.btn-close:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: left;
}
.btn-close {
  padding: 7px 10.5px;
}
footer {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0;
}
.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
#level-title {
  font-size: 2.85rem;
  margin: 2% 5%;
}
.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
.simon-rules {
  color: #fef2bf;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.simon-rules:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*****************************************colors*****************************************/
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 726px) {
  .btn {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 86px;
    width: 86px;
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
  .btn-close {
    padding: 5px 2.5px;
  }
  footer {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
  }
  #level-title {
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 1.85rem;
    margin: 4% 5%;
  }
}
```

the code in HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <title>Simon</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="level-title">Press Me To Start</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 btn-close">
          <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 btn-close">
          <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 btn-close">
          <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 btn-close">
          <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="fixed-bottom">
      <a
        href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Yqj76Q4jJ4"
        class="simon-rules"
        target="_blank"
        >What is Simon Game?</a
      ><br />
      &copy; Yash Salvi
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If possible  can anyone also help me know that on phone when user clicks on my "Press me to Start" i.e. on "h1" then I have used "h1" as a button and assigned the onclick function to it.Now the problem is that when user taps say on the "Press" it gets copied and browser asks if I want to do google search of the clicked word.
I want this "click to google search on any word" disabled.
[Text](https://raxy45.github.io/SIMON_GAME/) *Link to github page*

Comment: Is it possible you're using an old phone and its old browser? Because on my phone the border styles do appear perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah ! That's the only thing !.My bad.Thanks sir <3. Can you help me in remaining part of the problem . i.e. when user clicks on "h1" it gets added to google search.Do you encountered the same on your phone?

Comment: Well, I'd probably use a <button> instead

Comment: That would be the best way , no issue regarding that one. But is there any CSS property or even any HTML event attributes in that case which will allow me to achieve the same results?

Comment: Having a clickable h1 means you always run the risk of accidentally selecting the text; the more important question is why you don't want to use a button; it's not like you cannot style it to look like text (if that is what you want, for whatever reason)

Comment: Sorry for that one , I would surely use the button . And once again thanks for the help <3